# How do I enable responsive extension for DataTables?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

So the documentation says I need to add this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.5/css/dataTables.responsive.css">
```

and

```
responsive: true
```

So this is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.5/css/dataTables.responsive.css">

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "paging": false,
        responsive: true
    } );
} );
</script>
```

It isn't working.

Thanks in advance!

Here is the table. http://thesgn.com/board/index.php?pages/Members/

Comment: If you add your html code, it might help.

Comment: What version of Datatables are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot to include `dataTables.responsive.js` file. Besides you're using `<link>` tag in body which is not desirable the way you use it.

Please see [DataTables Responsive extension documentation](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) for proper initialization.

It's recommended that you put the  following code after your jQuery library `<script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>` in the `<head>` section to initialize DataTables and Responsive extension correctly.

```
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/css/jquery.dataTables.css"> 

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables Responsive -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.5/css/dataTables.responsive.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.5/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
```

However if you you're using CMS and can't or don't know how to edit the code in `<head>` section, alternatively you can put the following code anywhere in the `<body>`.

```
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link itemprop="css_datatables" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/css/jquery.dataTables.css"> 

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables Responsive -->
<link itemprop="css_datatables_responsive" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.5/css/dataTables.responsive.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.5/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
```

I see on your page that you're doing your own table styling, you may omit DataTables CSS in this case.

Comment: I'm using a forum software. Jquery is already included in the <head>. I'll try this when I get home. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work because in your own CSS you have `div.container { min-width: 960px; }` and your table is wraped in `<div class="container"></div>`. That is why it doesn't go smaller than that.

Comment: Based on your layout, it works if you remove `<div class="container"></div>` wrapper.